# How to compile QtWebKit on Qt5?

Tags: compilation, webkit, qt5, qtwebkit

I try to compile QtWebKit on Qt5 but I have a problem. Actually I implement next command "d:\qt_5.0.2\qtwebkit qmake" after that

I see "Running configure test..." but at all after that I have a problem "pkg-configure isn't inside or outside command using app or package file"

And then i get the error ->>  "Project ERROR: WebKit requires SQLite. Either make it available via pkg-config, set $SQLITE3SRCDIR or build WebKit under qt5.git."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly what the message tells you: you need sqlite sources to compile QtWebKit. Given you're under Windows, we can exclude the pkg-config way.

You have a copy of sqlite sources inside the `qtbase` repository, so you can do in your prompt

```
SET SQLITE3SRCDIR=D:\path\to\qtbase\src\3rdparty\sqlite
```

and then `qmake` and `make` as usual.

(Note that you're not building from qt5.git as the message suggest, but module by module. That has its pros and its cons. Having to manually manage module (inter)dependencies is one of the cons, as you've just figured out.)